# zRotation is not coordinated with movement

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uibezierpath

I'm trying to make a version of the game Vortex(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPN-vdeEsiE) of the iPod Classic for the iPhone with SpriteKit. I have this code so that the platform is orbiting around the center:

```
    let dx = base!.position.x - self.frame.width/2
    let dy = base!.position.y - self.frame.height/2

    let rad = atan2(dy, dx)

    path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: circle!.position, radius: (circle?.position.y)! - 191.39840698242188, startAngle: rad, endAngle: rad + CGFloat(M_PI * 4), clockwise: true)
    let follow = SKAction.followPath(path.CGPath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true, speed: 200)
    base?.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(follow))
```

But the problem is that the zPosition of the node is oriented to the path and not to the center as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nyG8.jpg).

It should rotate with this orientation: [image]

Please can someone help me with this, I'd appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like your ship rotation is off by 90 degrees. Seems like the simplest solution is just to rotate your source image by 90 degrees. That way you shouldn't need to change your code at all.

Comment: Thanks!, I can't believe I didn't see it before